# Can't authenticate user in Identity Server

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am trying to authenticate user in Identity Server 4 via **/connect/token** endpoint. I am filling all required fields in Postman:

- grant_type
- username
- password
- client_id
- client_secret

and I always get "**invalid_client**" response.

I have inserted values in next tables:

- AspNetUsers
- Clients
- ClientGrantTypes
- ClientSecrets

For table AspNetUsers in column PasswordHash I have added hashed password that is hashed with SHA256. In ClientGrantTypes I have added GrantType with value 'password' and inserted proper ClientId.

This is how my ConfigureServices look like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string connectionString = "Server=192.168.1.108; Port=5432; Database=Users; User Id=postgres;Password=RandomPassword123";
    var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
            {
                builder.UseNpgsql(connectionString, action =>
                {
                    action.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly);
                });
            };
        })
        .AddAspNetIdentity<Users>().AddConfigurationStore(options=>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
            {
                builder.UseNpgsql(connectionString, action =>
                {
                    action.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly);
                });
            };
        }).AddDeveloperSigningCredential();


    services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

I am struggling to figure out what am I doing wrong, so any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**:

I have included logging. This is the screenshot of what I have in Postman:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zczEK.png

And this is full log of Identity Server:

> [21:25:46 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Request path
>   /connect/token matched to endpoint type Token
>
> [21:25:46 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Endpoint
>   enabled: Token, successfully created handler:
>   IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
>
> [21:25:46 Information]
>   IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware Invoking
>   IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for
>   /connect/token
>
> [21:25:46 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint Start token
>   request.
>
> [21:25:46 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator
>   Start client validation
>
> [21:25:46 Debug]
>   IdentityServer4.Validation.BasicAuthenticationSecretParser Start
>   parsing Basic Authentication secret
>
> [21:25:46 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretParser Parser found
>   secret: BasicAuthenticationSecretParser
>
> [21:25:46 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretParser Secret id
>   found: Ryukote
>
> [21:25:46 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore
>   Ryukote found in database: False
>
> [21:25:46 Error] IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator No
>   client with id 'Ryukote' found. aborting

Log is confusing me cause there are stuff that are not true. That can be confirmed by looking at Postman screenshot I provided.

Comment: Identity service's console output\log file service will give you more information about why the client is invalid.

Comment: Thank you. I have included logging and I got a weird log. I will paste log and what I have in Postman in original post.

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from `BasicAuthenticationSecretParser` so I think you may have a Basic authorization header in your request to the token endpoint which contains

```
Authorization: Basic Ryukote:password
```

This is where IdentityServer is getting the client id 'Ryukote' from.

Remove the authorization header from your request.

Comment: Yes, but I still have invalid client error, but this time with different log outputs.

[17:38:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.HashedSharedSecretValidator
No shared secret configured for client.

[17:38:39 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretValidator
Secret validators could not validate secret

[17:38:39 Error] IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator
Client secret validation failed for client: randomclient.

Comment: The error is `No shared secret configured for client`.  Have you configured a shared secret for `randomclient`? Can you add the client configuration to your question?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/lz7oYO7.png that SHA256 value is "secret" in plain text. It is pointing to a ClientId "1" which I have also defined and that is "randomclient".